# LDAP username length

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I am testing a product which claims to fully support LDAP. We try to secure this product with our local Active Directory but I have noticed that usernames longer than 21 characters are cut off. I did some Google searches to determine whether LDAP only supports username less equal 21 characters but could not find any information. Does LDAP only support up to 21 characters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. LDAP by itself doesn't place any restriction on the username, especially as LDAP doesn't really specify which attribute qualifies as the username. The DN is similarly unencumbered. However, on Active Directory, the [`sAMAccountName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679635(v=vs.85).aspx) attribute only supports 20 characters.

Comment: Thanks. Are you saying that we should not have been able to use more than 20 characters for username in our AD?

Comment: That is exactly what they are saying. It is an Active Directory restriction on the specific attribute, sAMAccountName. LDAP strings are only bounded by available resources.

Comment: Technically, more recent versions of AD can use longer user names (using the `userPrincipalName` field, which has an unlimited length), but the `sAMAccountName` will only store up to 20 characters.